# Programmatically annotate an Excel chart

Tags: excel, vba

I'm being punished for not having a charge number. My penance is to do MS Office development on some program metrics spreadsheets that we have.

What I need to do in this instance is to annotate a line graph of requirements volatility with a comment that explains a spike.

The (potentially commented) data is contained in one spreadsheet, and the chart is automatically generated on a second spreadsheet in the same workbook when a button is pressed.

Google is giving me no love.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Almost all things which can be done manually can be done programmatically in Excel, too. Use the macro recorder to record the VBA code for making an annotation by hand. If you need some help to transform this code into a working program, post the code and give us some more technical details about your spreadsheet.

Comment: Ok, that's a start. The one item I found on the web said to set the value of the data label to be equal to a cell reference containing the text I need. This doesn't work for me, so the macro would give me no love. http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071002065751AAl4f79

Comment: Perhaps you should post a screenshot of what you trying to accomplish.